# cmake find modules wrt version

Tags: build, module, cmake, system

I have a question regarding CMake: recently a lot of modules have been added to the standard installation, such as GLEW or Mercurial.

However a lot of installation base might have an older version without all the new modules available, so you are forced to ship your own version of (eg) FindGLEW.cmake

Is it possible to check whether a given FindXXX module is available and in that case use it, otherwise supply a proper alternative? Or even check cmake version at runtime (but that's not always reliable and a pain to maintain)...?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default search behaviour of CMake's [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainclude) command w.r.t modules is:

> the file with name `<modulename>.cmake` is searched first in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, then in the CMake module directory.

(there's a bit more to it - see the docs or run `cmake --help-command include`)

What you're asking for appears to be the opposite to this; first check for an official module in the CMake module directory, and if none exists, fall back to use your own.

Assuming your modules are in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_cmake_modules`, you could reverse CMake's default behaviour by doing:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_cmake_modules)
```

If you name your own modules exactly as per the official ones, then this should achieve your goal.  If you wish to revert to the normal CMake behaviour later in your script, you can do:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_cmake_modules)
```

Comment: yep that's the behaviour I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as a possible alternative to the solution above, I found this cmake policy

```
CMP0017
   Prefer files from the CMake module directory when including from
   there.

   Starting with CMake 2.8.4, if a cmake-module shipped with CMake (i.e.
   located in the CMake module directory) calls include() or
   find_package(), the files located in the the CMake module directory
   are preferred over the files in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.  This makes sure
   that the modules belonging to CMake always get those files included
   which they expect, and against which they were developed and tested.
   In call other cases, the files found in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH still take
   precedence over the ones in the CMake module directory.  The OLD
   behaviour is to always prefer files from CMAKE_MODULE_PATH over files
   from the CMake modules directory.

   This policy was introduced in CMake version 2.8.4.  CMake version
   2.8.9 warns when the policy is not set and uses OLD behavior.  Use the
   cmake_policy command to set it to OLD or NEW explicitly.
```

Hope this helps.